# Rendering facelet without container (with or without Seam)

Tags: java, facelets, seam2

I would like to render a **facelets** page to **html** without running a web container. I've read that "Facelets does not depend on a web container" but I cannot do it.

I've tried Seam (v 2.3.1) which has a 'FaceletsRenderer' with no luck. The code:

```
new org.jboss.seam.ui.facelet.FaceletsRenderer().render("test.xhtml");
```

Gives the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.jboss.seam.ui.facelet.RendererRequest.cleanup(RendererRequest.java:72)
    at org.jboss.seam.ui.facelet.RendererRequest.run(RendererRequest.java:108)
    at org.jboss.seam.ui.facelet.FaceletsRenderer.render(FaceletsRenderer.java:43)
```

Anybody has any idea? Thanks in advance.